# Set working directory for entry point in setup.py

Tags: python

I have defined an entry point in my setup.py like this:

```
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
           'gpstest = src.gps:main',
        ],
    },
```

When I call `gpstest` from a directory X, the function is run from that directory X.
My goal is to be able to call `gpstest` from any directory but have the main function run in `gps/src` (so when I print the current working directory in `main.py` using `os.getcwd()` I want to get `.../gps/src` no matter from where I executed `gpstest`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Very often I just tend to use the  `__file__` variable which points to the current `script.py` location. To get the parent folder, I use `from pathlib import Path; Path(__file__).resolve().parent`. Although, this is a comment for getting the parent directory in general, not specific to your problem. Why do you need to use `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: The whole point of creating a python module is directory independence and a standalone utility. Your console_scripts serves as the entry point for this , your main function should contain your logics. I m not sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Do you have `src.gps:main` or `gps.src:main`? Could you show the relevant parts of your directory structure?